# iOS 8 - modal won't let you scroll

Tags: jquery, css, ios8

I have a modal, which I am opening in **Bootbox** (using the latest **Bootstrap 3.3.0**). The code is very simple:

```
$(document).on("click",".open-info-modal", function() {
    if (is_scrolling == false) {
        var the_el = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("notification"+$(this).attr('rel')) );
        var the_html = Mustache.to_html($('#leadPopupTemplate').html(), the_el);
        bootbox.alert(the_html,function() { });
        $('#the_message').css('height',$(window).height() - 150);
    } 
});
```

However, on iOS 8 (on my iPad), the scroll doesn't work correctly on **#the_message**. The annoying thing, is that it does sometimes. You have to click the modal, then click again to start trying to scroll.

The body is having **.modal-open** added to it ok, so thats not the problem. The annoying thing, is that it works on EVERYTHING apart from iOS8! (don't have an older version of iOS to test, so I can't check if it works on prior versions of iOS).

**UPDATE:** Ok, I give up - I've spent countless hours trying to get this to work, and  now just wish I'd looked at a 3rd party "jquery plugin" earlier. Ended up using this, and its fixed all my problems - http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Comment: what mobile browser are you using?

Comment: @henser they all have to use the same rendering engine so chrome, safari all render the same (excluding skyfire which renders in the cloud)

Comment: @henser - just using standard safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try multi-finger gesture to achieve scrolling in iOS. Sometimes this issue occurs.

Comment: Nope - should work with single finger, as a normal scroll. Just insane how much trouble this is! (I've done a ton of looking around on SO and also google, and still can't find a solution that fully works)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well not really an "answer" as such - but the only way I seem to be able to resolve this (as well as a new other annoying issues, such as the scrollbar not always being visible), was to use a 3rd party plugin:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

This fixed the focusing issue, and also allowed me to style the scrollbars a bit more.

Hope that helps someone else!